# React Naitve appending large string to useState([]) takes to long

Tags: arrays, react-native, optimization, react-hooks, chat

I am building my first React Native app and I am trying to use hooks to store a large array of {}. When I try to append a {} that has a short .content it appends instantly to the array. However, when the .content is a long string it takes a while until it's added to the array. what can I do to improve that? I am using it for a chat app. Is using hooks to store the messages the right call or should I do something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The technique when things get too large is to break them down. You are going in the right direction.

Without seeing your code, I recommend you do one of these

- break down large `useState` into multiple smaller ones
- only have one `useState` that will only keep the chat message that
  you show the user
- only have two `useState`, the first one you will read only(don't add
  anything to it often and depend on the reactiveness of react hook).
  Another one only keeps the chat message that you will show to the
  user. This one might need some kind of trial and error and logic to manage it beautifully.

The point is only to keep what you really need for the user.

Comment: I am using a FlatList. Is there a way I could do that and still be using FlatList?

Comment: @ItayLador Yes you can, FlatList. You can assign `useState` 's `state` to FlatList with no problem and manage it through `useEffect`. Otherwise, Please update the question with more information like code snippet, etc,etc